# Array em C - Como imprimir valores de um Array

Tags: c, array, vector

Como posso fazer para pegar essas informacoes do teclado, nome e valor de tres produtos, e imprimir em forma de tabela o nome com seu valor ao lado?

Fiz dessa forma (codigo no final), mas no momento aparece a mensagem "signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)"apos ler uma vez o nome e o valor.

Eu quero imprimir desse jeito:

```
 PRODUTO      PREÇO
  d          5.00
  l          4.00
  p          3.00
 TOTAL:       12.00
```

Codigo completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int i, t;
  char (mes)[20], produto[30][30];
  float valor_total, valor[30];
  char lista;

  printf("Lista de compras do mês.\n");
  printf("Digite o mes das compras:  ");
  fgets(mes,20,stdin);
   

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("Digite o nome do produto:  ");
    scanf(" %s", produto[i]);

    printf("Digite o preço do produto:  ");
    scanf(" %f", &valor[t]);

    valor_total += valor[t];
  }

     printf("Tabela de compra do mes de %s\n", mes);
     printf("PRODUTO      PREÇO\n");

     for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {     
     printf("%s          %4.2f\n", produto[i], valor[t]);
     }

     printf("TOTAL:      %4.2f\n", valor_total);



 return 0;

  }
```

Comment: `for (int t = 0; t < 1; t++)` não vejo pq usar esse for que só vai contar 1x, se só vai digitar 1 preço

Comment: Eu quero poder digitar o preço do primeiro produto e depois do segundo produto e assim sucessivamente, mas ainda nao consegui entender como faço isso alem desse modo. Se eu apenas tirar esse for indicado, o programa nao funciona, mas com ele, ele só pega o valor do ultimo produto atribuido e nao os 3.

Comment: se remover esse `for` e só tiver os printf/scanf do nome e depois do preço vai funcionar, ele vai ler em seguinda produto e preço, e vai fazer isso 3x, que é o que tem no primeiro `for`. Esse segundo for só faria sentido se digitar 3 preçso para cada produto, o que claramente não e o que que vc quer :)  **atenção** que "remover o for" não é só apagar a linha do `for`, tem que remover onde fecha a chave `}`

Comment: Eu fiz do modo que falou e apareceu a mensagem "signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)" apos perguntar uma vez produto e valor. {} apagado corretamente.

Comment: não da pra saber o que é "só imaginando" aqui, pode editar a pergunta e por o código nela, incluindo a declaração das variáveis antes do for

Comment: pronto, ajeitado.

Answer (score 1):

No segundo trecho, onde você imprime, você trocou os argumentos do for, compare com o par de for's do primeiro trecho, onde i = 1..3 e t = 1..1, enquanto no segundo trecho tanto i quanto t são de 1 a 3

```
printf("PRODUTO      PREÇO\n");

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    for (t = 0; t < 3; t++) {

    (...)
    }
 }
```

se você trocar o "t<3" do segundo for acima por "t<1", como é feito no primeiro trecho, você deve ter o que queria: imprimir apenas uma cópia de cada produto.

Comment: Sugiro usar a formatação de código disponível em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

Ao inves de

int i, t;
produto[i] e valor[t]

pus :
int i;
produto[i], valor[i]

e tudo se resolveu para ter a necessidade de apenas um loop.